# InvalidCastException on Generics

Tags: c#, generics, .net

Coming from the Java world, programming with generics and C# is often a headache. Like this one:

```
interface ISomeObject { }
class SomeObjectA : ISomeObject { }
class SomeObjectB : ISomeObject { }


interface ISomething<T> where T : ISomeObject
{
    T GetObject();
}
class SomethingA : ISomething<SomeObjectA>
{
    public SomeObjectA GetObject() { return new SomeObjectA(); }
}
class SomethingB : ISomething<SomeObjectB>
{
    public SomeObjectB GetObject() { return new SomeObjectB(); }
}


class SomeContainer
{

    private ISomething<ISomeObject> Something;

    public void SetSomething<T>(ISomething<T> s) where T : ISomeObject
    {
        Something = (ISomething<ISomeObject>)s;
    }
}


class TestContainerSomething
{
    static public void Test()
    {
        SomeContainer Container = new SomeContainer();
        Container.SetSomething<SomeObjectA>(new SomethingA());
    }
}
```

Which results into an `InvalidCastException` at `Something = (ISomething<ISomeObject>)s;`. In Java, this would work, and I could even use (if all else fails) the generics wildcard `<?>`. This is not possible in C#.

While this is just an example that I put together to explain the problematic, how can this exception be eliminated? The only main constraint is that `SomeContainer` **cannot** be a generic class

** **Note** ** : there are many questions about this, but none of them (that I could find) address a generic class member inside a non generic class.

** **Update** **

Inside the method `SetSomething`, I added these lines :

```
Console.WriteLine(s.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ISomething<SomeObjectA>)));
Console.WriteLine(s.GetType().ToString() + " : " + s.GetType().BaseType.ToString());
foreach (var i in s.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

which to my surprise output

```
False
SomeThingA : System.Object
ISomething`1[SomeObjectA]
```

Is this why I get this exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) keyword will be a fix, if your `ISomething` only have methods that return T

```
interface ISomething<out T> where T : ISomeObject
```

when creating a generic interface, you can specify whether there is an implicit conversion between interface instances that have different type arguments.

It is called [Covariance and Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

Eric Lippert have a good [series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) why we need to think about this, here [interface variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/26/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-interface-variance.aspx) is used

Here is my code, which works as expected for me

```
interface ISomeObject { }
class SomeObjectA : ISomeObject { }
class SomeObjectB : ISomeObject { }


interface ISomething<out T> where T : ISomeObject
{
    T GetObject();
}
class SomethingA : ISomething<SomeObjectA>
{
    public SomeObjectA GetObject() { return new SomeObjectA(); }
}
class SomethingB : ISomething<SomeObjectB>
{
    public SomeObjectB GetObject() { return new SomeObjectB(); }
}


class SomeContainer
{

    private ISomething<ISomeObject> Something;

    public void SetSomething<T>(ISomething<T> s) where T : ISomeObject
    {
        Something = (ISomething<ISomeObject>)s;
    }
}


class TestContainerSomething
{
    static public void Test()
    {
        SomeContainer Container = new SomeContainer();
        Container.SetSomething<SomeObjectA>(new SomethingA());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `out` but it gives me some error (no line) about not being able to load the `ISomething_IMpl'1'` from the assembly :)`

Comment: which version of .net are you using? as I remember it become available in .net 3+, I am on .net 4 and it works

Comment: The latest, I had ".Net 4 Client Profile" and changed to ".Net 4" but same result. For the record, I just changed `interface ISomething<T> where T : ISomeObject` for `interface ISomething<out T>`.

Comment: Yes, I juest tried it and it says that I cannot load the interface because it declares an argument of type covariant which is neither an interface or a delegate. Funny, isn't it? BTW : I have all the updates installed, .Net 4, VS2010 Ultimate (legit) and all.

Comment: @YanickRochon, are you trying the same interface as here? could you please copy exact error message please, I am not sure why you can get that messag? are you trying this in one project?

Comment: The error message is in french, I tried to translate it :) And, yes, I'm using the exact same interface as here, except it's in the ns `TestApplication.generics`, but I don't think it really matters. Anyway, here's the actual error message : `Impossible de charger le type 'TestApplication.generics.ISomething_Impl\`1' à partir de l'assembly 'TestApplication_Accessor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', car il déclare un paramètre de type covariant ou contravariant et il n'est pas une interface ou un délégué.`

Comment: Hmm, that is realy interesting, Are you in unit test envirement? in which type of application are you checking? I wonder if we meet this bug in vs2010. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/609849/vs2010-c-unit-tests-wizard-generates-code-with-private-accessor-errors-for-covariant-generic-parameters

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20351/discussion-between-arsenmkrt-and-yanick-rochon)

Comment: Yes! This is exactly it! I had a unit test project attached and it failed to compiled. It managed to work when I unloaded the project from the solution... wow... This is probably one of my most ridiculous error/workaround (wtf? moment) with .Net that I've had so far. It probably even beats my previous "there is an unknown error caused an unknown exception in an unknown source" (VS2003) :)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is useful to let a generic interface implement a non generic one to circumvent the missing `<?>`

```
interface ISomething
{
    object GetObject();
}

interface ISomething<T> : ISomething
    where T : ISomeObject
{
    T GetObject();
}

public class SomeImplementation<T> : ISomething<T>
{
    public T GetObject()
    {
        ...
    }

    object ISomething.GetObject()
    {
        return this.GetObject(); // Calls non generic version
    }
}
```

A collection can then be typed with the non generic interface

```
var list = new List<ISomething>();
list.Add(new SomeImplementation<string>());
list.Add(new SomeImplementation<int>());
```

Comment: This is interesting. I thought all objects inherited from `object`. And having two interfaces of the same name, one being generic and not the other one... is plain weird to me.

Comment: However the problem here is that the method `GetObject` needs to have a specific implementation for each concrete type, thus why the generics, and I need to set a concrete implementation to some non-generic class (`ISomething` must be inter-changeable inside `SomeContainer`)